# The ms-python.python plug-in in the vscode remote environment has the wrong PATH path order in the remote Linux

Tags: python, conda, centos7, vscode-remote

Remote-SSH Log：

```
(base)[dev@localhost web_vpn]$ conda activate flask_web
(flask_web)[dev@localhost web_vpn]$ echo $PATH
/home/dev/.vscode-server/bin/0ee08df0cf4527e40edc9aa28f4b5bd38bbff2b2/bin/remote-cli:/usr/local/cuda-12.1/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17.0.8/bin:/bin:/home/dev/miniconda3/envs/flask_web/bin:/home/dev/miniconda3/condabin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/dev/.local/bin:/home/dev/bin:/home/dev/miniconda3/bin:/home/dev/.vscode-server/bin/0ee08df0cf4527e40edc9aa28f4b5bd38bbff2b2/bin/remote-cli:/usr/local/cuda-12.1/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17.0.8/bin:/bin:/home/dev/miniconda3/bin:/home/dev/miniconda3/condabin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/dev/.local/bin:/home/dev/bin
(flask_web)[dev@localhost web_vpn]$
```

Environment:

```
Remote environment: linux centos7
ms-python.python plugin version: v2023.22.1

Operating environment:
  VScode Version: 1.85.1 (user setup)
  Submitted: 0ee08df0cf4527e40edc9aa28f4b5bd38bbff2b2
  Date: 2023-12-13T09:49:37.021Z
  Electron: 25.9.7
  ElectronBuildId: 25551756
  Chromium: 114.0.5735.289
  Node.js: 18.15.0
  V8: 11.4.183.29-electron.0
  OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22621
```

I'm using the python plugin (it's plugin id is: ms-python.python), above is the vscode remote startup, I switch conda to the virtual environment "flask_web", you can see that "(flask_web)" is already in front of it. However, when I use echo $PATH to check the environment variable, "/bin" is in front of "/home/dev/miniconda3/envs/flask_web/bin" in the conda virtual environment directory. " in front of it.
However, when I connect to the server using xshell's ssh and start the "flask_web" virtual environment, the first $PATH is the bin directory of the conda virtual environment.
I've tried a lot of things on the internet, such as changing the remote server setting:

```
"terminal.integrated.env.osx": {
        "PATH": ""
},
"terminal.integrated.inheritEnv": false
```

None of these apply, it is still /bin that takes precedence over the bin directory of the conda virtual environment in the vscode remote's $PATH. This also results in me using python commands in vscode remote's shell, launching an older version of python in /bin, and not being able to use the python virtual environment that I really need.

But the good thing is, when running the python program using ctrl+F5 at that time, it runs the command:
`(base)[dev@localhost web_vpn]$ /usr/bin/env /home/dev/miniconda3/envs/flask_web/bin/python /home/dev/.vscode-server/extensions/ms- python.python-2023.22.1/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/adapter/... /... /debugpy/launcher 58218 -- /home/dev/dev/web_vpn/test.py` 
Starts python in the conda virtual environment directory directly with parameters (this is not affected by the $PATH variable, since python in the virtual environment is started via an absolute path). So the conda virtual environment is used correctly when python is running.

The following is from the environment contribution of the vscode terminal, you can see that the ms-python.python plugin seems to set the $PATH variable backwards in the remote environment, advancing the root directory to "/bin", but this only happens in the remote case, in the local one. Running the code locally does not cause this problem.

```
## Extension: ms-python.python

Environment is enabled. `~/miniconda3/envs/flask_web/bin/python`

- `CONDA_ROOT=/home/dev/miniconda3`
- `CONDA_PREFIX_1=/home/dev/miniconda3`
- `PATH=/home/dev/.vscode-server/bin/0ee08df0cf4527e40edc9aa28f4b5bd38bbff2b2/bin/remote-cli:/usr/local/cuda-12.1/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17.0.8/bin: /bin:/home/dev/miniconda3/envs/flask_web/bin:/home/dev/miniconda3/condabin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/ home/dev/.local/bin:/home/dev/bin:${env:PATH}`
- `CONDA_SHLVL=2`
- `CONDA_PREFIX=/home/dev/miniconda3/envs/flask_web`
- `CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV=flask_web`
- `CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER=(flask_web) `
- `PS1=(flask_web) ${env:PS1}`
```

Thank you very much!

I hope to be able to solve the problem of the wrong order of $PATH on the remote server by modifying the configuration of the relevant vscode or ms-python.python plug-in.

Answer (score 0):

家人们，研究了一个上午终于解决了，这个方法也算是曲线救国吧。

It's already been resolved, another way to find other options instead.
In the setting.json file of the vscode remote, add the following configuration:

```
"terminal.integrated.profiles.linux": {
        "bash with custom PATH": {
            "path": "/bin/bash",
            "args": ["-c", "exec bash --init-file <(echo 'right_conda_name=$CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV; source ~/.bashrc; conda activate $right_conda_name"]]
        }
    }
```

The principle is to run the command in args before opening a new terminal, which saves the correct conda "env" virtual environment name, and then after creating the terminal, activate the corresponding conda environment with this correct virtual environment name.

Comment: Please translate/replace the initial line, as SO is supposed to be English only.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).